# Trouble deleting iterations in array

Tags: c++, arrays, iteration

In this code, I'm trying to remove all occurrences of a specified value from an array.  Function should take three arguments, the array, the array length and the value being searched for. Each time the value is found, the array should be shifted to remove that value.

This is what I have so far:

```
void arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value){
   for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
       {
       if(arr[i] == value)
           {
            for (int k = i; k<length ; k++)
               {
                   arr[k] = arr[k+1];
               }
           arr[length-1] = 0;
           }
        }
}
```

The code is successful when these are the values used:

```
int inputarray[] = {10,20,30,40,50,10};
int length = 6;
int value = 10;
//output: 20 30 40 50

int inputarray[] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; 
int length = 4;
int value = 6;
//ouput: 7 8 9

int inputarray[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60}; 
int length = 6;
int value = 70;
//output: 10 20 30 40 50 60
```

However, the code doesn't work when:

```
int inputarray[] = {9,8,9,9,9,9,6}; 
int length = 7;
int value = 9;
//what I get: 8 9
//what I want: 8 6
```

I can't seem to figure out why my code fails when iterations are in play.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: Shifting the whole (tail of) array in (possibly) each iteration causes the square time complexity O(n^2) of your program. See my answer for a linear-time approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your O(n^2) algorithm fixed. For linear complexity, see CiaPan's answer.

```
void arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == value)
        {
             for (int k = i; k < length ; k++) // condition should be k + 1 < length, otherwise k + 1 is out of bounds
                 arr[k] = arr[k + 1];

             i--;      // you want to decrement i here cause current element has been removed, thus i is already index of the next element
             length--; // you should also decrement length
             arr[length] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also return new length, or pass length by reference to know the size after...

Comment: Thank you!  Looking at the solution, I feel kind of silly not even trying that.

Comment: Don't forget to return the new size of the used portion of the array.

Comment: O(n^2) to empty the array if it contains all items equal `value`

Comment: @CiaPan I've just supplemented OP's algorithm.

Comment: See linear time complexity approach in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Scan the array and copy items different from `value` to the array's beginning.
Variable `j` is a copy destination index, so it gets incremented on each copy.
The final value of `j` is a number of copied items, that is a resulting array length – return it, so a caller knows what part of `arr[]` it may use.

```
int arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value){
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
        if(arr[i] != value)
            arr[j++] = arr[i];

    /* you may also zero the tail of array,
       but it doesn't seem necessary if you return j
    */
    for(i=j; i<length; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;

    return j;   // new length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `i = 1` the array is `{8,9,9,9,9,6,0}` and `array[i]` is looking at the first `9`.

When `i = 2` the array is `{8,9,9,9,6,0,0}` and `array[i]` is looking at the second `9`.

Since `i` will only move forward from this point, there is no way to get rid of the first `9` in the array with your current function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just as ajarusan said,

Lets explain it.

for the code

```
int inputarray[] = {9,8,9,9,9,9,6}; 
int length = 7;
int value = 9;
```

For `i=0`, `arr[i]` is `9` and it is swapped and the array becomes

```
8 9 9 9 9 6
^
i=0
```

Now for `i=1`, `arr[i]` is `9` and it is swapped. The array after swapping becomes

```
8 9 9 9 6
  ^
  i=1
```

But then, it goes to `i=2` next and that causes the `9` at the index `1` to be skipped. After swapping the `9` at index `2`, the array becomes

```
8 9 9 6
    ^
    i=2
```

As you can see, the `9` at `i=1` is not changed.
This is what is causing the problem.

To fix this just add a `i--` as indicated here

```
void arrayShift(int arr[], int length, int value){
   for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
       {
       if(arr[i] == value)
           {
            for (int k = i; k<length ; k++)
               {
                   arr[k] = arr[k+1];
               }
           arr[length-i] = 0;   // I changed to length - i
           i--;                 // added i--
           }
        }
}
```

Well, that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a common mistake: you are so used to iterating through an array with a `for` loop that you haven't really thought through what you're doing.

If your array is this

```
1 2 3 4
  ^
```

and you're looking at the indicated element, if you don't want to remove it you advance

```
1 2 3 4
    ^
```

But if instead you want to remove it, you change the array to

```
1 3 4
  ^
```

and now you *don't* want to advance because you're already at the next element.

Thus, you'll have to make a different loop structure than usual (you'll probably want to use `while`), so that you can tell it to advance only when you don't delete the element.